# VAR($p$) estimation

Tags: estimation, vector-autoregression, intuition, generalized-least-squares, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

I am bit stumped by this result.
Source: Remark on page 46 of Multivariate Time Series Analysis by Rsay.
... one can obtain the GLS estimate of a VAR($p$) model equation by equation. That is, one can consider the $k$ multiple linear regressions of $z_{it}$ on $x_t$ separtely, $i=1,\ldots,k$.

If this is true, and as the previous page shoes $\hat{\beta}$ does not depend on $\Sigma_a$, i.e. the coefficients do not depend on the covariance matrix of the $k$ components of the disturbance; even if they were uncorrelated that answer would have been same!

I fail to intuitively digest this result. How can correlation information among the $k$ components not effect the parameters at all!!

Any explanation, hints, links are appreciated!

Comment: multivariate regression (not multiple regression) has direct links to GLS and VAR, and is also called multi-tasking in the supervised learning framework. I recommend Izenman https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-78189-1_6?utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=commission_junction&utm_campaign=3_nsn6445_brand_PID9149765&utm_content=de_textlink&countryChanged=true

Comment: @develarist I think i did understand the derivation and see why $\Sigma_a$ should not be a part of the answer. I am just looking to understand it on a more intuitive level. There must be something which can intuitively suggest that the coefficients would be independent of the cross covariances.

Comment: also look into Greene Econometric Analysis for multivariate regression, GLS and VAR